# download .jad file from OTAInstall on my webserver

Tags: blackberry, webserver

I have developed an appliation for blackberry and built it.I have 2 folders OTAinstall and StandardInstall...

I have placed my OTAInstall file on the server.I navigate to the .jad file for installing it on my mobile..but i am unable to download..do i miss any step in deploying it on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `.htaccess` file on your web-server, to recognize .jad and .cod files properly.

Add the following lines to your `.htaccess` file on your web-server.

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod cod
```

Comment: +1.  just a note that this can also be put in your httpd.conf file (for apache, obviously).